# Add NavigationDrawer toggler by replacing back navigation in action bar

Tags: android, actionbardrawertoggle

I have an activity in my app which is not launcher.
I want to add a navigation drawer with toggler. I tried following the instructions here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon

But my back navigation still shows up (It exits the app as I have added appropriate flags to the intent)
How can I show the drawer toggler icon ?

Also android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggler is deprecated, what should I use instead ?

Comment: do you want menu icon instead of back right?

Comment: I want to replace the back icon with an icon which opens the drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggler is deprecated to use new one get support library supporv7 appcompact check here https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

and creating Navigation drawer here you get all information
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

code sample

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

use the latest support library you will get done it easily and not use setHomeasUpEnabled(true)

Comment: It says that I have to replace ActionBar with ToolBar. In https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) the argument required is a https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html   Is there a standard toolbar for navigation drawer or do I have to make one from scratch ?

Comment: you can make simple toolbar and set it as action bar runtime.
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); it will work like normal actionbar